# no age_range in facebook response (javascript sdk)

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk

I need to get age range for the user himself (not friend)

As per https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user

`user_range` is part of the `/me` node. But, I decoded the response object and there is no `age_range` over there.

I am using facebook javascript sdk. Is age_range available? how? is it still accessible through the '`signed _request`'?

Answer (score 1):

I was accessing the `/me` node via the graph API.

I found out that the age_range is not returned with the root object but to get `age_range`, I need to issue the following API call

```
me?fields=age_range
```

This gives me a JSON obejct age_range that has min and max values.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to explicitly tell the API that you need age_range, as part of the public profile (no special permissions required). The user's age range may be 13-17, 18-20 or 21+.

```
/* make the API call v.2.3 */
FB.api(
    "/me?fields=age_range",
    function (response) {
      if (response && !response.error) {
        /* handle the result */
      }
    }
);
```

read documentation https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/age-range/